# Good Sites for CPU Reference?

Tags: discussion, resources

One of the more difficult areas to make decent recommendations with any degree of speed is in the CPU department, especially now that we are entering an era where not everything is so x86, clock-speed -centric. The old x86 architecture is not only increasingly diverse within its own ranks, but is also now seeing competition from other CPU architectures: especially ARM, but also FPGA, MIPS, POWER8, etc. in some cases.

What resources can we recommend people take a look at when answering questions or formulating their own questions? I tend to have a lot of experience in the x86 space, so I can make a recommendation or two there, but I am missing any real resources when it comes to ARM and other architectures.

Comment: Great question! The same could be asked for many other types of hardware that are diversifying as of late. This will definitely help people out in the future.

Comment: @Adam I've got to say, this question scares me a little bit. It feels like those opinion-based questions that would immediately be closed. Obviously, it's the community's choice, but I feel like something like this should be put into a canonical answer either on main, or a canonical answer on meta (but has a meta feel).

Comment: I fully agree. What part of the question makes you think I want something different? I'll edit that right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x86 (and x86-64/IA64) specification comparison, I have found that [cpu-world.com](http://www.cpu-world.com/) has no real competition. While it unfortunately doesn't offer enough information about CPU-chipset compatibility or benchmarks, it does pretty much everything else in a fast, easily-used interface, and it keeps up to date.

Comment: I am also adding as a commentary that http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/index.html has not yet steered me wrong in all my years of this hobby.

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the benchmarks that I use.

- [3DMark](http://3dmark.com/search) benchmark (physics with same GPU)
- [Cinebench](http://cbscores.com/) scores
- [Anandtech generalized benchmarks](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/CPU/39)
- [Tom's Hardware generalized benchmarks](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/cpu-charts-2015/benchmarks,187.html)
- [Passmark benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php)

For comparison I generally look at manufacturer's websites

- [ARK intel](http://ark.intel.com/)
- [AMD Products](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors)

Hopes this helps.

Comment: As was already mentioned, this is more about spec comparison between CPUs; benchmarks should definitely be something we talk about, but separately. 

The major issue with your manufacturer website approach that I see is that you cannot easily compare AMD against Intel, and AMD's site is... kinda terrible.

Comment: @AdamWykes AMD's site is not beautiful, but, well, it works...

Comment: Try to find multiplier info, steppings, and instruction sets on that site. I can't.

Answer (score 0):

For computer processors, [PassMark's CPU Benchmarks](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/) is a great site to compare the performance of CPUs. It uses information from community ran benchmarks which allows it to have a huge variety of different CPUs tested.

Comment: That is the exact site I would choose for generalized CPU benchmarks/performance comparisons. However, J personally have noticed that their stats and nomenclature is sometimes misleading or flat out wrong, so I can't recommend them as a spec reference site.