# Canon questions and answers

Tags: discussion, resources

I'm recently started to design a high-end desktop from scratch. Since I haven't done anything like that in a long time, I've been scouring this site for relevant question.

The thing is, the good questions are buried beneath the rest. And I got the distinct feeling I'm actually looking for meta questions, like [this one](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/516/56).

I'm not in a hurry. The parts won't be ordered till December. But I suspect many of the questions I have, have already been answered. I simply can't find them. I vaguely recall I've seen some very good questions in the past though, so there must be something out here.

> What are the canonical questions, meta or not, about picking the right parts for a desktop?

This is a list question. Partial answers are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for questions that give general advice on "what to look for when buying X hardware", you're out of luck. Questions of that type have been [off-topic since Oct 29 '15](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want-general-advice-questions).

There are still a few questions of that type around that were kept because they were asked before that scope was decided, and were high-quality enough to be worth keeping. Here are a few:

- [monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-should-i-consider-when-buying-a-gaming-monitor)
- [processor performance](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-evaluate-processor-performance-when-comparing-processors)
- [SSD vs. HDD](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/330/will-switching-to-ssd-improve-my-write-performance)
- [routers](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/107/when-looking-to-buy-a-router-for-home-use-what-are-the-specs-features-that-i-sho)
- [is hyperthreading worth it?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-i-find-a-processor-with-hyper-threading)
- [smartphone cameras](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-should-i-look-for-besides-pixel-density-count-when-choosing-a-smartphone-wi)

That's just about all I can find (half of which I had to resort to mod abilities to find, so there aren't that many anyway)

If those don't answer your questions, then think about what you want each component to have, or to be, or to do etc, then ask a question that details those things. One question per component, each with specific requirements, should get you some good answers, and may even form the basis of a 'canonical' question for people to come.